# Finding the values of $t$ such that the limit is zero.

Tags: calculus, limits

> Let a real valued sequence ${x_n}$  such that
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n\cdot (x_n) = 0$$
>
> Find all possible real numbers $t$ such that
> $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n \cdot (\log n) ^ t = 0$
>
> [Source](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission2017/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGB-2020.pdf)

My approach was to use the Epsilon-Delta definition which results in
$|n x_n| <  \varepsilon$

This does not help in any way...a rigorous proof is needed.

Comment: Why was the answer deleted ?

Comment: Why would you start with the epsilon delta relation..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any real number $t$, $|x_n(\log n)^t|=|nx_n|\left|\frac{(\log n)^t}{n}\right|$ and since $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}nx_n=0$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{(\log n)^t}{n}=0$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}x_n(\log n)^t=0$ so any $t$ fits.

Comment: IMO, $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{(\log n)^t}{n}=0$ is what you have to prove.

Comment: That follows easily from $\log(n)/n \to 0$. I don't think we have to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

We need to show that $\log^t(n)=o(n)$, which is fairly obvious for $t\le 0$.

Now equivalently, for $t>0$,

$$\log(n)=o(\sqrt[t]n)$$

and

$$\log(m^t)=o(m)$$

and

$$\log(m)=o(m).$$