# Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)^t}{n} =0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Context: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3929759/finding-the-values-of-t-such-that-the-limit-is-zero).

If you take the expression as a continuous function of $n$, then the limit is arrived at by continuously hitting the expression with L'Hospital's rule. In the discrete case, I tried Stolz-Cesàro but it didn't help much:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\left[\ln(n +1) \right]^t -\ln(n)^t}{1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)^t}{n}  $$

Comment: Why is it that you don't usually accept or give feedback to answers on your questions?

Comment: If you can show that the limit equals $0$ in the continuous case, then surely this means that it equals $0$ in the discrete case.

Comment: Hi, please invite me in the chat, I'll discuss in there @NinadMunshi

Comment: How is that implied @Joe

Comment: I, uh, am not sure how to do that haha. I created a room but I don't know how to invite users to it.

Comment: @Buraian: To clarify, do you want to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(n)^t}{n} =0$ for integer $n$? If so, then you want to show that for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is an $N>0$ such that if $n>N$, then $\left|\frac{\log(n)^t}{n}\right|<\varepsilon$, where $n\in\Bbb{N}$. However, if you have proven that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log(n)^t}{n}=0$ in the continuous case, then you have the stronger statement that there is a $N>0$ such that if $n>N$, then $\left|\frac{\log(n)^t}{n}\right|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\in\Bbb{R}$ (so, in particular, it is true for $n\in\Bbb{N}$).

Comment: *Hint*: Show the log of the expression tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: You could substitute $n=e^x$ and then kill the numerator by repeated application of L'Hospital (or just use the fact that $\exp$ grows faster than any polynomial).

Comment: Nice, I didn't think both would give the same result in the continuous case. If you post that as answer I'll accept it. @Joe

Comment: Sent a message @NinadMunshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can show that the continuous limit, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln(n)^t}{n}$, is equal to $0$ via repeated application of L'Hôpital's rule. So by definition for every $\DeclareMathOperator{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}\epsilon>0$ there is an $N>0$ such that, for all $n\in\Bbb{R}$, if $n>N$, then $\left|\frac{\ln(n)^t}{n}\right|<\epsilon$. In particular, if $n\in\Bbb{N}$ satisfies $n>N$, then $\left|\frac{\ln(n)^t}{n}\right|<\epsilon$. Hence, the discrete limit is the same as the continuous one.

Answer (score 1):

For $t>0:$ Let $n=x^t.$ Then $x\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$. And for $1\le n\in\Bbb R$ we have $$\frac {(\ln n)^t}{n}=\frac {(\ln (x^t))^t}{x^t}=t^t\cdot \left(\frac {\ln x}{x}\right)^t.$$ So it suffices to prove $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac {\ln x}{x}=0.$